# Serialize Modelstate to XML asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

Im trying the serialize the modelstate to an xml string. First I create a modelstate dictionary and this dictionary I try to serialize. This is the code I use:

```
 ModelStateDictionary dict = new ModelStateDictionary();
            dict.Merge(ModelState);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(dict.GetType());

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()){
                serializer.Serialize(writer, dict);

                var r2 = writer.ToString();

            }
```

r2 is created, but all tags are filled with \r\n. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a XmlWriter and specify in the settings that you don't want to keep whitespaces and indentation:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(dict.GetType());
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false };
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, dict);
    string r2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This indeed strips off the /r/n tags. My problem (and maybe I didnt specify it correctly is that although there are values in the modelstatedictionary object there are no values in the xml.

Comment: the problem is that the serializer can't serialize KVP's. Im now looking into custom libraries to do this.